# Как расположить div поверх других блоков div?

Tags: html, css

Как расположить div поверх других блоков div? Чтобы было как на рисунке. Тот div, который нужен поверх других, выделен синим цветом (остальные - белые).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте позиционирование CSS. В данном случае надо второму белому блоку задать свойство `position: relative;`, а синему блоку задать `position: absolute;`, чтобы он позиционировался относительно второго белого блока. Не забудьте указать `top: 0;` и  `left: 0;`. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position) или [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)

Answer (score 0):

используйте свойства `position: absolute;` и `z-index: 100` (например 100, просто чтобы быть выше остальных) для позиционирования требуемого блока

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  
  margin-bottom:  10px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.super {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:  100;
  top:      45px;
  
  width:    50px;
  height:   75px;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class = 'block'></div>
<div class = 'block'></div>
<div class = 'block'></div>
<div class = 'super'></div>
```